# Jest previous test result leaking into next test

Tags: jestjs, redux-toolkit

I have written this RTK slice for createAPI.

```js
    // notificationApi.slice.js

    import config from '../../config/default'
    import { prepareHeaders } from '@/utils/request'
    import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
    import { PAGE_SIZE } from '@/constants/notifications'
    import { mapNotification } from '@/utils/notification'
    import Notifications from '../../services/notifications'
    const NOTIFICATION_URI = '/scheduler/'
    const url = (config.apiGatewayV2 || config.apiGateway) + NOTIFICATION_URI
    let notificationsHandler;
    export let notificationsHandlerExists = false;
    export const notificationApi = createApi({
      reducerPath: 'notificationApi',
      baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: `${url}`,
        prepareHeaders,
      }),
      endpoints: (builder) => ({
        fetchNotifications: builder.query({
          query: (pageNumber) => {
            const pageSize = PAGE_SIZE
    
            return {
              url: 'notifications',
              params: { pageNumber, pageSize },
            }
          },
          transformResponse: (response) => {
            if (!response.data) {
              return response
            }
            response.data = response.data.map((item) => mapNotification(item))
            return response
          },
          transformErrorResponse: (response) => {
            console.error(response.error)
            return response.status
          },
          forceRefetch: () => {
            return true
          },
          onQueryStarted: async (_, { dispatch, getState }) => {
            const user = getState().application.user;
            if (!notificationsHandler) {
              console.log('notificationsHandler starting a fresh')
              notificationsHandler = new Notifications(user.id, async () => {
                await notificationsHandler.open();
                // Trigger the fetchNotifications query
                await dispatch(notificationApi.endpoints.fetchNotifications.initiate(undefined));
              });
            } else {
              console.log('notificationsHandler already exists')
              notificationsHandlerExists = true;
            }
          }
        }),
      }),
    })
    
    export const { useFetchNotificationsQuery } = notificationApi
```

And then my testcase is like below

```js
    import { renderHook, waitFor, act } from '@testing-library/react'
    import { useFetchNotificationsQuery, notificationsHandlerExists, notificationApi } from './notificationApi.slice'
    import moment from 'moment'
    import { renderWithProviders } from '@/utils/test.utils'
    import fetchMock from 'jest-fetch-mock'
    import Notifications from '../../services/notifications';
    fetchMock.enableMocks()
    
    jest.mock('@/utils/request', () => ({}))
    jest.mock('../../services/notifications');
    beforeEach(() => {
      fetchMock.resetMocks()
      jest.clearAllMocks()
    })
    
    
    
    describe('useFetchNotificationsQuery', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules();
        fetchMock.resetMocks()
        jest.clearAllMocks()
      })
      describe('When notification api response error', () => {
        it('Should return object with data as undefined', async () => {
          fetchMock.mockReject(new Error('Internal Server Error'))
          const { Wrapper: wrapper } = await renderWithProviders('')
          const { result } = renderHook(() => useFetchNotificationsQuery(1), {
            wrapper,
          })
          await act(async () => {
            const initialResponse = result.current
            expect(initialResponse.data).toBeUndefined()
            expect(initialResponse.isLoading).toBe(true)
    
            await waitFor(() => {
              const nextResponse = result.current
              expect(nextResponse.data).toBeUndefined()
              expect(nextResponse.isLoading).toBe(true)
              expect(nextResponse.isError).toBe(false)
            })
          })
        })
      })
    
    
    
      describe('onQueryStarted callback', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          jest.resetModules();
          fetchMock.resetMocks()
          jest.clearAllMocks()
        })
        it('should initialize NotificationsHandler if not exists', async () => {
          const { Wrapper: wrapper } = renderWithProviders('')
          const { result } = renderHook(() => useFetchNotificationsQuery(1), {
            wrapper,
          })
    
          await act(async () => {
            // Mock the getState function to return the required state
            notificationApi.getState = jest.fn(() => ({
              application: {
                user: {
                  id: 'mockUserId',
                },
              },
            }));
    
            // Call the query function
            await result.current[0];
    
            // Assert that NotificationsHandler is initialized
            expect(fetchMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // Assuming the fetchNotifications query triggers a fetch
            // Add more assertions based on your specific implementation details
    
            // Verify that the Notifications constructor is called
            expect(Notifications).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            // Optionally, you can also check the constructor arguments or other details
            expect(Notifications).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mockUserId', expect.any(Function));
          });
        })
    
        
    
        it('should use existing NotificationsHandler if it already exists', async () => {
          // Simulate an existing notificationsHandler
          let notificationsHandler = new Notifications('existingUserId', jest.fn());
    
          const { Wrapper: wrapper } = renderWithProviders(''); // You need to implement renderWithProviders function
          const { result } = renderHook(() => useFetchNotificationsQuery(1), {
            wrapper,
          });
          await act(async () => {
            // Mock the getState function to return the required state
            getState = jest.fn(() => ({
              notificationApi: {
                application: {
                  user: {
                    id: 'mockUserId',
                  },
                },
              },
            }));
    
            // Call the query function
            await result.current[0];
            // Expect notificationsHandlerExists flag to be false
            expect(notificationsHandlerExists).toBe(true)
    
            // Assert that NotificationsHandler is not initialized again
            expect(fetchMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
            expect(Notifications).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // Simulation of existing notificationsHandler
          })
        })
      })
    
    })
```

Here is whats happening , so here in `RTK createAPI slice` , in the `onQueryStarted callback` I check if `notificationsHandler` already exists. The first testcase `'When notification api response error'` checks `notificationsHandler` doesn't exists and creates one. Second testcase `'should initialize notificationsHandler if not exists'` again comes to `onQueryStarted callback` and this time it see the previously created `notificationsHandler` already exists and persistance and skips and hence the testcase is failing.

How to address this. I tried mocking the `notificationApi.slice.js` and `jest.clearAllMocks()` at `beforeEach` but it didn't help either.

So my first testcase is consoling `'notificationsHandler starting a fresh'` and next 2 `notificationsHandler already exists` .

Comment: The problem is not with tests. The problem is `notificationsHandler` and other stuff are initialized upon import. Running the JS in the module should do nothing by itself. You should define functions and/or classes in the module and then run functions to do initialization.

Answer (score -1):

From [Nux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333296/nux)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77695972/jest-previous-test-result-leaking-into-next-test?noredirect=1#comment137032174_77695972), the problem could be related to how `notificationsHandler` and potentially other variables are being initialized upon import.
That approach can lead to shared state across tests and unexpected behavior, as you have experienced.

In JavaScript and Node.js modules, any code that is not inside a function or class gets executed immediately upon import. That can cause issues in a testing environment where you expect each test to start with a clean slate.

To avoid this, you should refactor your module to avoid side effects upon import. Instead of executing code directly, encapsulate behavior in functions or classes. That way, you control when and how the code is executed.
And, rather than initializing variables like `notificationsHandler` at the module level, provide a function to initialize them. That function can be called explicitly when needed, ensuring better control over the state.

Your refactored module would then be:

```js
// Before refactoring
let notificationsHandler;
export let notificationsHandlerExists = false;
// other code that initializes notificationsHandler

// After refactoring
let notificationsHandler;
export let notificationsHandlerExists = false;

export function initializeNotificationsHandler(user) {
  if (!notificationsHandler) {
    notificationsHandler = new Notifications(user.id, /* */);
  } else {
    notificationsHandlerExists = true;
  }
}

// In your endpoint
endpoints: (builder) => ({
  fetchNotifications: builder.query({
    // 
    onQueryStarted: async (_, { dispatch, getState }) => {
      const user = getState().application.user;
      initializeNotificationsHandler(user);
      // 
    }
  }),
})
```

`initializeNotificationsHandler` is the function that you call explicitly within `onQueryStarted`. It avoids the issue of having `notificationsHandler` initialized upon import.

In your tests, you now have more control over when `notificationsHandler` gets initialized. You can choose to call `initializeNotificationsHandler` explicitly in each test or mock it as needed. That approach should resolve the issue of shared state between tests, as the initialization of `notificationsHandler` will now be under your control, happening within the test's execution context rather than upon module import.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be working for me. I am getting same issue.

Comment: @Dibshare I have edited the answer to leave some debugging suggestions, but which approach did you take? `jest.resetModules()`, or explicitly reset the `notificationsHandler` state before each test?

Comment: @Dibshare I have rewritten the answer based on Nux's comment.